# Ошибка в клавиатуре python bots

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите в каком месте ошибка.
Код:

```py
keyboard_helper = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard_helper.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Канал №1", url="https://t.me/+j93xiVb545"))
SendMsg(userid, donattions(),msgid,reply_markup=keyboard_helper())
```

Ошибка:

> TypeError: 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' object is not callable

Comment: Проверьте тип InlineKeyboardMarkup и его значение. Он у вас не вызываемый объект. Поэтому интерпретатор выбрасывает ошибку, когда пытаетесь вызвать его как функцию. types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

Comment: не совсем вас понял, можно решение?

Comment: TypeError: SendMsg() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reply_markup' , написал как вы сказали

Comment: @Alex. Значит SendMsg не имеет соответствующего параметра reply_markup. Может сначала получше базовый питон изучить и как минимум с документацией библиотеки ознакомиться? А то вы так и будет на каждом шаге спотыкаться.

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте последнюю строчку на:

```
SendMsg(userid, donattions(),msgid,reply_markup=keyboard_helper)
```

То есть уберите скобки. Вы вызываете клавиатуру как функцию, а не как объект